# This content is download the PDF using selenium and python. I can not get a url from the new generated tab

Tags: python-3.x

What is happening is this ... I am building an algorithm that is entering the site, doing a captcha break, using the OCR method, soon after, using a Web Scraping in a  HTML. .. Lately there is a  where  tag where download opens a new tab with the PDF of which I want to download (PDF VIEW CHROME). If you want, you can either download your URL or simply download it.

I've already tried using driver.find_element

def web_scraping(self):
        url = self.__driver.current_url
        response = requests.get(url)

```
    if response != 200:
        try:
            rows = WebDriverWait(self.__driver, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@id='Grid1ContainerTbl']/tbody[1]/tr[*]"))
            )
            for i in range(2, len(rows) + 1):
                try:
                    row_xpath = "//table[@id='Grid1ContainerTbl']/tbody[1]/tr[%s]/td[*]/span[1]" % (str(i))
                    cols = self.__driver.find_elements_by_xpath(row_xpath)
                    table_xpath = "//table[@id='Grid1ContainerTbl']/tbody[1]/tr[%s]/td[*]/input[1]" % (str(i))
                    self.__cols_table = self.__driver.find_element_by_xpath(table_xpath)
                    for x in range(len(cols)):
                        if x == 0:
                            continue 
                        #print(cols[x].text.encode('utf-8'))
                        self.trat_pdf()
                except:
                    pass
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

        time.sleep(0.5)
        buttom = self.__driver.find_element_by_class_name('PagingButtonsNext')
        buttom.click()
    else:
        self.__driver.close()
        return Main()

    self.next_page()

def next_page(self):

    self.web_scraping()
```

try:
    Main()
except:
    pass